# What is my method of rendering the Mandelbrot set called?

Tags: complex-analysis, fractals

Recently I've dived into studying complex analysis on my own and it led me to find an interesting way of displaying the Mandelbrot set:

Consider $$f(f(f(f(...x))))$$
Then, 
$$ \frac{d}{dx} (f(f(f(f(...x))))) = f'(f(f(f(...x))))\cdot f'(f(f(...x)))...$$
Assuming that this function converges for $x$, 
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f(f(...x))) =  \prod_{p=1}^{\infty} f'(f^{p}(x))$$
Since all non-edge-points in a Julia set always diverge or converge to the same cycle, this gave me an idea. Even though this product is always equal to $0$ or $\infty$, I wondered if it was possible to still compare the derivatives by how quickly they converge to $0$. I thought about the best way to do this for a while and came up with the following expression to color the points in the Mandelbrot set:
$$ 1-4\sqrt[p]{ \prod_{i=1}^{p} d(v_{i}) }$$
where $p$ is the length of the cycle the point converges to, $v_i$ is the $i$th point of the cycle, and $d(x)$ is a function which returns the squared distance of $x$ from the origin. The radical normalizes the value of the product based on the length of the cycle, in effect determining the "average" value of $f'(f^p(x))$. Finding the cycle and its values can be done efficiently using pre-existing algorithms. When I made a program to implement this algorithm, I got the following really cool image:

[image: The Mandelbrot set image I rendered]

If this has been done before, what is this method of displaying the set called?

Comment: You might also seek answers at the Fractal Forum (http://www.fractalforums.com/).

Comment: I've personally called it "interior coordinates", though I don't know if there is a more "official" term out there.. https://mathr.co.uk/blog/2013-04-01_interior_coordinates_in_the_mandelbrot_set.html

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mandelbrot_set_-_multiplier_map.png

Comment: https://gitlab.com/adammajewski/mandelbrot-book_book see Interior Coordinates (code and image  by Claude ) and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/def_cqp#Multiplier_map

Comment: @Claude You mention Newton's Method in that post. Originally I thought you were using it to find the special points in the set where $f^p(x)=0$. Is this true?

Comment: @2.71828-asy no, I'm using Newton's method to find one of the $p$ points in the limit cycle $f_c^p(x)=x$.  The initial starting point for Newton iterations should be $x_p$, which will be near zero (in fact only $p$ where $|x_p|$ is smaller than any previous $|x_i|$ (apart from $x_0 =0$) need to be considered).

Comment: @Claude Okay, I understand what you're saying now. It looks to be pretty much the same thing I'm doing, except you are using the points to map to an image.

Comment: @2.71828-asy actually it's not quite the same - your method gives progressively darker colouring for Mandelbrot islands of higher periods (try around $-1.9990956823270185 + 0 i$ with a view radius of $5 \times 10^{-7}$, for example), while the "interior coordinates" method makes the Mandelbrot islands look the same as the whole set

Comment: @Claude True. I am correct in saying that your algorithm doesn't just place images inside the bulbs, but rather maps each pixel inside the set to a pixel on a source image using the cycle of the point right?

Comment: Yes it uses the derivative of the cycle as coordinates for an image (which can be generated procedurally or looked up in a bitmap).  The derivative is $0$ at the superattracting nucleus and has magnitude $1$ at the boundary.